# Every $k$-connected graph is $k$-edge connected.

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

> **Give a proof or a counterexample:** Every $k$-connected graph is $k$-edge connected.
>
> Definition: A graph is $k$-connected if its connectivity is at least $k$. The connectivity of $G$ is the minimum size of a vertex $S$ such that $G-S$ is disconnected or has only one vertex.
>
> Definition: A graph $G$ is $k$-edge connected if every disconnecting set has at least $k$ edges.

I thought this was false, but apparently it is true.

The graph I came up with was:

[image]

For instance, it is 2-connected, since we need at least $2$ vertices to disconnect it (those vertices in purple on the left). But it is 3-edge connected.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is not a counterexample. It is $2$-edge connected because every disconnecting set has at least $2$ edges. Just because there exists a stricter lower bound of $3$ doesn't mean it isn't $2$-edge connected.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read this: [Menger's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger%27s_theorem)